# Isometric Sprites

Tags: c++11, sfml, isometric

This might be a stupid question but I'm stuck and can't get passed it. I'm making a isometric game and I have my map built using tiles, I just followed this tutorial to build the map, http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/creating-a-city-building-game-with-sfml/137. But now I don't know how to add character sprites. Do I have to add these sprites using tiles as well or do I just draw the the sprites into position of the screen. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from the engine, just follow the "Textures and Animations" guide and draw the Animation to the screen after you have drawn the tiles. This isn't a complicated engine, so you are only working with 2D sprites being drawn to the screen (the 3D effect is merely tricks of painter's algorithm to make it work...there is no z-axis from what the tutorial indicates)

Comment: Yeah that's what I done first but felt wrong so taught I would ask before wasting more time. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. **The depth is done by the order of tile rendering**

   The same goes for objects,players,etc...  Let assume plane **XY** is parallel with the ground and **Z** axis is the altitude. Then your grid would be something like this (assuming diamond shape layout):

   [image: diamond shape layout]
2. **Order of rendering**

   You have to handle object,players and stuff sprites in the same way as tiles (and in the same time). so you should render all cells in specific order dependent on your grid layout and sprite combination equation. If your sprites can overwrite already rendered stuff then you should render from the most distant tiles to the closest to the "camera". In that case the blue direction arrow on above image is correct and **Z** axis should be increasing in the most inner loop.

   **So now if you got any object,player or stuff placed in cell `(x,y,z)` then you should render it directly after the cell `(x,y,z)` was rendered prior to rendering any other cell**.

   To speed up is a good idea to have objects and players in your tile map as a cell. But for that you have to have the tiles in the right manner and also your map representations must be capable of doing so.